# Issuing, accessing, and using api tokens with Laravel 5 and Angular 4

Tags: angular, api, authentication, laravel-5, token

I am building an SPA with Laravel 5.5 and Angular 4. I am confused about the "best" (safe, secure, best practices, etc) way of authenticating my api requests. At present, I have a traditional session-based login system, which, after the user has logged in, redirects to the index page of my Angular application- where the entirety of the application is contained. All subsequent interaction with the server is done through api calls.

Following some basic tutorials, I have the following setup: each user is assigned a 60-character random string which serves as their api token. After they've logged in, using their username and password, the api token is outputted directly to the HTML in a `meta` tag in the header. Angular then grabs this token and passes it in the header of each api call.

However, I've since read that tokens shouldn't be passed over non-SSL connections (to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks), and that tokens should be auto-generated / set to expire etc.

So my questions:

- For a single page app, using only internal api calls (not cross-domain). Is it reasonable to pass unencrypted api tokens in this way?
- Is it OK/safe to output the api token directly into the HTML in a Meta tag?

On the last point, this seems to be standard practice for using Laravel's CSRF token? Perhaps I've just read too many paranoid blog posts?

Answer (score 0):

In modern web programming, you can never have too many tokens. There are **access tokens**, **refresh tokens**, **anti-XSRF tokens**, and more.

> It’s the last type of token that I’ve gotten a lot of questions about
>   recently. Specifically, does one need to protect against cross site
>   requests forgeries when building an API based app?

In any application where the browser can implicitly authenticate the user, you’ll need to protect against cross-site request forgeries. Implicit authentication happens when the browser sends authentication information automatically, which is the case when using cookies for authentication, but also for applications using Windows authentication.

> Generally, **APIs don’t use cookies for authentication**. Instead, **APIs
>   typically use bearer tokens**, and custom JavaScript code running in the
>   browser must send the token along by explicitly adding the token to a
>   request.

However, there are also APIs living inside the same server process as a web application and using the same cookie as the application for authentication. This is the type of scenario where you must use anti forgery tokens to prevent an XSRF.

Your Project or App is:

1. **Laravel is your API services**
2. **Angular 4 is your client App**

> The best way is using token-based services and below link is for laravel
>   5.5 for creating token and authenticating token and for users using apis: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not currently using passport. I'm simply creating my own api_token per user, as described in this blog post: https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51 

Do you think this is reasonable for a small scale SPA? And is it OK - in your opinion- to output the token into the html page, and then grab it with `document.getElementById("token")` ?

Comment: if you using angular for your frontend app, best way is using a service inside angular that store token for a period of time and any time your app need to authenticate from api use it and don't output token inside html page isn't reasonable for api-based apps, I have similar problem, always use simple way to solve your problem not difficult way

Comment: How would you get the token initially? If you're making an initial api call when the app first loads to request the token for the current user, then I guess that api call itself still needs to be verified somehow? What are the security issues with outputting the token to html? Thanks